# How to add a NLog custom renderer to a custom target programmatically

Tags: nlog

I'm configuring NLog programmatically with a custom target and a custom layout renderer.

If I was doing this in XML, I would have the following definition:

```
    <targets>
    <target name="logLambda" xsi:type="LambdaLoggerTarget" layout="${lambdalogger-json}" />
    </targets>
```

How can I add this layout programmatically? In my config code, I have:

```
        public static void Init()
        {
            var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

            LayoutRenderer.Register<LambdaLoggerLayout>("lambdalogger-json");

            var lambdaTarget = new LambdaLoggerTarget
            {
                Name = "LambdaLoggerTarget",
            };
            config.AddTarget(lambdaTarget);

            config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, lambdaTarget);

            // Apply config           
            NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
        }
```

I was assuming, in my lambdaTarget instantiation, I could find a way to specify a Layout, but I haven't found that.

Thanks!

Comment: var lambdaTarget = new LambdaLoggerTarget
            {
                Name = "LambdaLoggerTarget",
                Layout = "${lambdalogger-json}",
            };

Comment: @RolfKristensen - This definitely moves things forward. I can see in the "Write" method that my renderer is defined as "${lambdalogger-json", but my renderer's DoAppend method is not called. This looks like: [LayoutRenderer("lambdalogger-json")]

Comment: Are you missing curly-bracket ? `"${lambdalogger-json}"` Else you can enable `NLog.LogManager.ThrowConfigExceptions = true` as the very first thing in your code (Before creating `new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration`)

Comment: Btw. when you say `DoAppend` then it sounds like that `LambdaLoggerLayout` inherits from `AspNetLayoutRendererBase`. And the rule is that [DoAppend](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_Web_LayoutRenderers_AspNetLayoutRendererBase_DoAppend.htm) is only called when inside a valid HttpContext.

Comment: You are correct on the AspNetLayoutRendererBase. I wasn't getting any exceptions (and I fixed my missing "}"). To make it work, I also overrode the Append method and from there called DoAppend. Thanks for your help and let me know if I should do it differently. If you add your answer as a response, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```cs
LayoutRenderer.Register<LambdaLoggerLayout>("lambdalogger-json");

var lambdaTarget = new LambdaLoggerTarget
{
   Name = "LambdaLoggerTarget",
   Layout = "${lambdalogger-json}",
};
```

If your `LambdaLoggerLayout` inherits from `AspNetLayoutRendererBase`, then it will only call `DoAppend` if active HttpContext is found.